# What does dharma as a goal mean in purusartha?

Tags: dharma, purushartha

The four goals of human existence are called purushartha and consist of dharma, artha, kama, and moksha. Here what does it mean to attain dharma as a goal? Why is dharma considered to be a goal?

Comment: Dharma is not a goal but the means. Dharma is how everything is functioning naturally and what we need to do as human and following that path correctly is Dharma!

Answer (score 2):

Srimad Bhagavata Purana explains why kama and artha cannot be the ultimate goals of man. Dharma as a goal means one has to understand that kama and artha are not ultimate goals. A person living in accordance with Dharma has the opportunity to attain moksha, the ultimate goal of life. It is in this sense that Dharma is considered as a goal.

Strictly speaking Dharma is a goal for a householder. He is given this goal as otherwise he will strive recklessly for the fulfillment of kama and artha.

> Dharma, understood as the Supreme Good of man, **can never have wealth
>   as its reward**. **Nor has wealth, understood as an aid to the
>   achievement of Dharma, been conceived as an aid for the attainment of
>   kama (sexual desire)**. **Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence
>   in sexual pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to
>   make life unbroken.** And as for life, it has the quest of the Supreme
>   Truth as its end – not certainly Karma (i.e. performance of rituals
>   and social duties) for the attainment of wealth (prosperity here and
>   heaven hereafter).

Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.2.9-10